# Android Kotlin listview adapter filter shows only first item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I've made a custom ArrayAdapter to populate my lists, and I added edittext to filter listview but the listview is filtering only first item.

XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/invoiceSearchFilter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search invoice"
    android:padding="15sp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewInvoiceSearchList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
```

Kotlin:

```
var listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listViewInvoiceSearchList)
var adapter = InvoiceSearchListAdapter(this,idList, titleList, descList)

var thefilter = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.invoiceSearchFilter)
listView.adapter = adapter
thefilter.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
    
                }
    
                override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
                    (listView.adapter as InvoiceSearchListAdapter).filter.filter(charSequence)
                }
    
                override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
    
                }
            })
```

ListView is correctly displayed with all entries but why I enter text to filter list, it only filter first item.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to filter the query as below Hope it helps also use `toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())` to avoid case sensitive:

```
charSequence.forEach { q ->
           (listView.adapter as InvoiceSearchListAdapter).filter.filter(q)
        }
```

Comment: Won't this repeatedly change the filter, and finally apply a filter that looks at only the final character?